# Sorting integers in a string with TSQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql, sorting

I am trying to sort a string such as '3,9,6' to '3,6,9' with TSQL. My approach was extracting the characters from the string, casting them as integers and putting them into a #temptable using a primary key for sorting. For this I created this procedure:

```
create proc sortstring(@string varchar(50))
as
    declare @limit int = len(@string)
    declare @counter int = 1
    declare @temps char
    create table #temptable (tempstring varchar(30) primary key)
        while @counter<=@limit
            begin
                set @temps = SUBSTRING(@string,@counter,1)
                    if(@temps!=',')
                        insert into #temptable values (CAST(@temps as int))
                set @counter= @counter+1
            end
```

After this process, I was thinking to extract the integers from #temptable with a while loop to create the sorted string format '3,6'9'. But I think my whole approach is not performance efficient.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method should be a bit better than the while loop

```
declare @string varchar(255) =  '3,9,6,0,5,12,88,15,23,45,77,88,125,1'
declare @TableList table (tmpStr int)

DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = '<root><csv>' + replace(@string, ',', '</csv><csv>') + '</csv></root>'

INSERT @TableList
SELECT replace(Word.value('.', 'integer'), CHAR(10), '') 
FROM @XML.nodes('/root/csv') AS WordList(Word)

select * from @TableList order by 1
go
```

Comment: Thank you I have no idea that we could achieve this by using xml

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TableList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TableList

create table #TableList (tmpStr int)
declare @string varchar(255) =  '3,9,6,0,5,12,88,15,23,45,77,88,125,1'

SET @string = 'SELECT ' + REPLACE(@string,',',' UNION ALL SELECT ')

SET @string='INSERT INTO #TableList (tmpStr) ' + @string

EXEC( @string)

SELECT * FROM #TableList ORDER BY tmpStr
```

Its not a conventional approach but it runs fast.

Comment: Thanks, as you said it is not a conventional approach but it is very elegant.